# .htaccess trouble with cakephp and addon domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add an addon domain with its own site to my hosting account which already has a cakephp setup.

I was experiencing a 500 error on the addon domain, but I managed to remove this using the solution at: http://expertsoverflow.com/questions/21345626/htaccess-addon-domain-issue-gives-500-error

Now my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain\.co.uk [NC] 
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]

RewriteCond ^seconddomain\.report [NC]
RewriteRule    (.*) http://seconddomain.report/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now my addon domain works as expected but my main domain isn't correctly forwarding image/file requests to the app/webroot folder so none of the images and css are loading and no pages work past the first index.

For reference the initial cakephp .htaccess file was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: my folder structure:

Main domain:
/public_html/
/public_html/app/webroot/

Second domain:
/public_html/seconddomain/

Comment: Your second condition makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Can you go to the developer console in your browser, then go to the network tab and reload the page with missing images and css. Inspect what urls it tries to load for the images/css and what return code it gives.

Comment: Thanks Sumurai8, I removed the second line and it continues to work. The files being tried to load are http://www.maindomain.co.uk/css/normalize.css which is correct but in the folder document on the server I need them to be pointing to http://www.maindomain.co.uk/app/webroot/css/normalize.css (without displaying this URL to the visitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the directory of the addon domain.

Rather than having the addon domain in /public_html/seconddomain/ it is now /seconddomain/ in root. Then I'm just using the standard .htaccess files for cakephp in the /public_html/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very late but i got a solution for it.

Add the rewrite rule in primary .htaccess file:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
        RewriteEngine on 
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} seconddomain.report
        RewriteRule seconddomain.report/ - [L] 

        RewriteEngine on 
        RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L] 
        RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L] 
   </IfModule>
```